# How to write the query result from a variable to a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, variables

What I want to achieve here is to get the result from the `CheckSum_Agg(Binary_CheckSum(*))` and write this to a table with the matching `TABLE_NAME`.

The query below is something I came up with, but it's missing the next step to write the query result to a table.

```
DROP TABLE  HashTable
CREATE TABLE    HashTable
    (
        HashTable nvarchar (255),
        TABLE_NAME nvarchar (255)
    )

INSERT  HashTable
EXEC master..sp_MSForeachdb 'USE [?]
IF DB_ID(''?'') > 4
SELECT ''SELECT CheckSum_Agg(Binary_CheckSum(*)) AS HashTable FROM '' +  TABLE_CATALOG + ''.'' + ''dbo'' + ''.'' + TABLE_NAME AS HashTable
,TABLE_NAME AS TABLE_NAME
FROM ?.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = ''BASE TABLE'' 
'
```

Updated the question, because I think I wasn't clear enough.

The result that I get now is something like:

`SELECT CheckSum_Agg(Binary_CheckSum(*)) AS HashTable FROM DatabaseX.dbo.tblX`.
A desirable result would be the checksum value itself, something like `1971451`.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.objects WHERE type = 'U' and name = 'testHashTable')
  DROP TABLE testHashTable

CREATE TABLE testHashTable
    (
        HashTable nvarchar (255),
        TABLE_NAME nvarchar (255)
    )
GO
INSERT INTO testHashTable
EXEC master..sp_MSForeachdb 'USE [?]
IF DB_ID(''?'') > 4
SELECT ''SELECT CheckSum_Agg(Binary_CheckSum(*)) AS HashTable FROM '' +  TABLE_CATALOG + ''.'' + ''dbo'' + ''.'' + TABLE_NAME AS HashTable
,TABLE_NAME AS TABLE_NAME
FROM ?.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = ''BASE TABLE'' 
'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following ways:

```
INSERT INTO testHashTable
EXEC master..sp_MSForeachdb 'USE [?]
.....
```

OR

```
EXEC master..sp_MSForeachdb 'USE [?]
IF DB_ID(''?'') > 4
INSERT INTO master.dbo.testHashTable
...
..
```

BUT, If you are planning to use this code for long term then **avoid using sp_MSForeachdb**, this object is not documented and not supported by Microsoft. Try to replace your code using Loop or Cursor (there should not be issue as the count of databases can be considered.).